# Different size of images does not fit in viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I want to load images into imageview of viewpager receiving from webservice. Images received are in different sizes. so, due to different image sizes space between two images keeps changing and alignment disorders. Things to achieve as shown in below images are:

- shapes of all images should be appropriate
- space between two images must be same
- adjacent images (images at left and right edges) should be monochrome (black and white)
- all the images should be on same x-axis

Links and demos i followed are:
[Multiviewpager](https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager)
[commonsware blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)
[viewpager-container](https://github.com/RudreshJR/ViewPagerContainer?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4793)
[carousel-viewpager](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/carousel-viewpager/)
[CarouselViewPager](https://github.com/mrwii/CarouselViewPager)
[Carousel-Layout-by-ViewPager](https://github.com/DevExchanges/Carousel-Layout-by-ViewPager)

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off with RecyclerView for such a task. Look at [this](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/09/android-tip-recyclerview-snapping-with.html) example.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved almost 3 out of my 4 queries. Just monochrome image is left now. Thanks again.

Comment: @DhruvaShastri feel free to accept my answer if it helps ;) For your monochrome image handling I would suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) then you can handle grayscaling as described [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-custom-transformation)